# create whatsapp link on opencart to send order details manually

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am creating a WhatsApp link on the order_info.twig page link to contact no. Its like when I click on the contact number order details go to the buyer for COD (cash on delivery) order verification.

following is the code I wrote.

[{{ telephone }}](https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91%7B%7B%20telephone%20%7D%7D&text=Hello%20%7B%7B%20firstname%20%7D%7D%20%7B%7B%20lastname%20%7D%7D%0A%0AThank%20you%20for%20shopping%20with%20*Whitedot%20Sports*.%0A%0A*Here%27s%20your%20order%20summary:*%0A%0AOrder%20ID:%20%7B%7Border_id%7D%7D%20%0A%0A*Products:*%0A%7B%7Border.product.name%7D%7D)

but I am not getting the order product information. How can I get that?